# NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'surname' was called on null

Tags: android, json, flutter, response

I am running a `login` process with custom `BaaS`. The submit button runs an `onPressed` method which checks `Response response;` `if reponse.statusCode == 200` then send `fromJson(reponse.data).surname` and `fromJson(response.data).firstname` to `Homepage` screen. I have set up the passage to `Homepage` screen and it works but when I try to `Hot Reload` the app then try to access Homepage, it throws `NoSuchMethodError` `I/flutter (14935): The getter 'surname' was called on null.` How do I solve this problem?

I have tried assigning the `widget.data.surname` to a random `string` in the `initState` it clears up the error but it doesn't re-assign the `widget.data.surname` and `widget.data.firstname` to `fromJson(reponse.data).surname` and `fromJson(response.data).firstname`

```
class Data
{
  String surname = '';
  String firstname= '';

  Data ({this.surname, this.firstname});
}
```

```
Response response;
          Dio dio = new Dio();
          response = await dio.get(findUrl, queryParameters: {"username": _username, "password": _password});
          print(response.statusCode);

          if(response.statusCode == 200){
            print(UsersInfo.fromJson(response.data).surname);

            userSurname = UsersInfo.fromJson(response.data).surname;

            userFirstname = UsersInfo.fromJson(response.data).firstname;

            var data = Data (
              surname: userSurname,
              firstname: userFirstname
            );

            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: "Login successful",
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                timeInSecForIos: 6,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0
            );

            Future.delayed (Duration(seconds: 7),
                    () async {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(data: data))
                  );
                  print('7 seconds');
                }
            );
          }
```

Second Screen (Homepage screen)

```
Data data;

  HomePage ({this.data});
```

```
enum AuthStatus {
  notSignedIn,
  signedIn
}
```

```
AuthStatus _authStatus = AuthStatus.notSignedIn;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      widget.data = Data (surname: '', firstname: '');
       _authStatus = ((widget.data.surname == '')) ? AuthStatus.notSignedIn : AuthStatus.signedIn;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in Widget is final. Keep one version in state if you change it there. And then in initState do:

```
_data = widget.data ?? Data();
```

Edit: I left out important note. Don't call setState in initState, it's not build yet, and any data you set there will be there on first draw.

And change Data class so it will have default parameters:

```
class Data{
  final String surname;
  final String firstname;

  Data ({this.surname = '', this.firstname = ''});
}
```

Or you could even add factory that extracts from UsersInfo object:

```
Data.fromUsersInfo(UsersInfo info) : firstname = info.firstname, surname = info.surname;
```

Then in onPressed method you can make data just with:

```
var data = Data.fromUsersInfo(UsersInfo.fromJson(response.data));
```

I'm not sure what else are you doing with that data but this should work :)

Comment: Thanks I will try it out and get back to you

Comment: I have tried what you said but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: What did you mean by `Keep one version in state if you change it there`?

Comment: All I did after making the changes was to restart my Intellij IDE and it worked. Thanks a million.

Comment: Sorry wasen't here. But yeah just to keep second instance of the data object in state class, so you don't reassign widget.data. Then you call setState with that changed instead of changing widget.data, (since that field should be final and not changeable).